# ReactJS: how to map JSON elements sequentially and show the hidden div on click

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops

I'm trying to load items from JSON and toggle a dropdown div with description on click. While I can display elements sequentially (ex: `loc1 & desc1, loc2 & desc2`) on static divs I'm having trouble finding out how to render it properly when the second part (desc) is hidden and only shows when the loc div is clicked.

What would be the best way to map the result so it doesn't show as `loc1 & loc2, desc1 & desc2` but as `loc1 & desc1, loc2 & desc2`?

Code:

```
var places = {
  library: {
    location: [
      {
        loc_name: "library1",
        "desc": "desc1 : Modern and spacious building"
      },
      {
        loc_name: "library2",
        "desc": "desc2 : A cosy small building"
      }
    ]
  }
};



function contentClass(isShow) {
  if (isShow) {
    return "content";
  }
  return "content invisible";
}

class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isShow: false };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(function (prevState) {
      return { isShow: !prevState.isShow };
    });
  }

  render() {

    const libraries_desc = places.library.location.map((libr) =>
      <div>
        <p>{libr.desc}</p>
      </div>
    );
    const lib_names = places.library.location.map((libr) =>
      <div>
        <p>{libr.loc_name}</p>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <div className='control' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <h4>{lib_names}</h4>
          <div className={contentClass(this.state.isShow)}>{libraries_desc}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



render((
  <Toggle />
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Current result:

```
library1
library2
desc1 : Modern and spacious building
desc 2 : A cosy small building
```

Desired Result:

```
library1
desc1 : Modern and spacious building (hidden but shown when clicked)

library2
desc 2 : A cosy small building (hidden but shown when clicked)
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wq2mokn02l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try extracting a location into a separate component. By extracting it, each location is responsible for knowing its state. In your case, that means its visibility (controlled by `this.state.isShow`).

Here's how you could do it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

var places = {
  library: {
    location: [
      {
        loc_name: "library1",
        "desc": "Modern and spacious building"
      },
      {
        loc_name: "library2",
        "desc": "A cosy small building"
      }
    ]
  }
};

class Location extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isShow: false };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(function (prevState) {
      return { isShow: !prevState.isShow };
    });
  }

  contentClass(isShow) {
    if (isShow) {
      return "content";
    }
    return "content invisible";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='control' onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <h4>{this.props.desc}</h4>
        <div className={this.contentClass(this.state.isShow)}>{this.props.loc_name}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const locations = places.library.location.map(location => {
      return <Location {...location} />
    })

    return (
      <div>
        {locations}
      </div>
    );
  }
}



render((
  <Toggle />
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Toggle` Component should be like this.

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { 
       isShow: false,
       id: -1, // initial value
     };
   }

   handleClick = (id) => {
    this.setState({ 
      isShow: !this.state.isShow,
      id: id
    });
   }

   render() {
     const { location } = places.library;
     const { isShow, id } = this.state;
     return (
       <div className="control">
          {location.map((libr, index) => (
            <div key={index} onClick={() => { this.handleClick(index) }}>
              <p>{libr.loc_name}</p>
              {(isShow && (id === index)) && <p>{libr.desc}</p>}
            </div>
           ))}
       </div>
      );
   }
}
```

So when you click on the `div` element. A click event will be triggered called `handleClick` which will pass the `index` as a param to the function. which will set isShow to false or truth and vice versa along with the current element you want to show which will be selected through `this.state.id`. So everytime `isShow` is true and `this.state.id` matched `index` element of the array. Your description will show otherwise it will be hidden as you want.

So your desired result will be something like this.

```
library1
desc1 : Modern and spacious building (hidden but shown when clicked)

library2
desc 2 : A cosy small building (hidden but shown when clicked)
```

Comment: It's showing a syntax error on closing tag of location.map((libr, index), even though it's closing properly. Why would that be so?

Comment: It was missing a `(` at the end of. map() I have fixed it.  kindly look at the code in render methid again